# Displaying an image in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, bundle

I'd like to dislay an image in UIWebView using

```
<img src="imageInBundle.png"/>
```

The above image is in my bundle.  I load it, along with other HTML in a string, like this:

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.abc.com"]];
```

However, I just get a blue box with a white question mark.  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change the

```
[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.abc.com"]
```

to a

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]
```

where path is something like

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

...depending where the image is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using `UIImageView` instead to display this image?

Comment: How do you dynamically execute a UIImageView embedded in string?  Not that I'd really want to.