# How to display locally stored images with a UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

**When Connected:** 
I have a simple HTML page with some image elements that reference images in a subdirectory as in (src="images/someimage.jpg"). This page displays fine when accessed remotely via an internet connection.

**When Offline:** 
I store the above HTML page locally to the apps documents directory for offline viewing. The local HTML page is loaded and displayed fine with the UIWebView -- the PROBLEM is that the images in the HTML file are **NOT** displayed.

**Possible Cause:**
I guess the problem might be that the image paths (`<img src="photo_files/..." />`) are not resolved to absolute paths locally? How do I get it so that I can display local images in a UIWebView without modifying the html source? I don't wanna have to go in there and manually change each of the image paths to the documents directory paths...How do I get the local images to display correctly on my UIWebView?

**Question:**
How do I get it so that I can display local images in a UIWebView without modifying the html source?

*(Assume valid local paths .../Photos/photos.html, and Photos/photo_files/(image files).jpg all under the documents directory path)*

HTML page source

...

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Photo Gallery</h1>


<img src="photo_files/app_IMG_01.jpg" /><br />
<img src="photo_files/app_IMG_0100.jpg" /><br />
<img src="photo_files/app_IMG_0066.jpg" /><br />


</body>
</html>
```

Objective-C source

...

```
    NSFileManager* myManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  

    if([myManager fileExistsAtPath:[[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Photos/photos.html"]]){

        NSLog(@"Loading Saved Copy!");
        urlAddress = [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Photos/photos.html"];


        //Create a URL object.
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Photos/photos.html"] isDirectory:NO];
        //URL Requst Object
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        //Load the request in the UIWebView.
        [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053288/displaying-an-image-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this was not working for me. It was related to something totally different. UIWebView does not seem to have any problems with relative paths.